# Javascript fromCharCode keyCode

Tags: javascript

I need the keycodes for something but I don't know what kind of keycode it is, I couldn't find it anywhere else.

```
 function keyDown(e) {
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "%") isLeft = true;
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "'") isRight = true;
}

function keyUp(e) {
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "%") isLeft = false;
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "'") isRight = false;



}
```

I figured out that % is left arrow and ' is the right arrow, could anyone tell me what kind of keycode thingy this is? or maybe how I could change it to a better one.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find keycode values by googling for "javascript keycodes", or just use this website: [keycode.info](http://keycode.info/)

The keycode for left arrow is 37, right arrow is 39.

In your code you converted `e.keyCode` to an ASCII character, which is unnecessary. Unsurprisingly, ASCII character #37 is `%`, #39 is `'`.

Just compare the keycode values directly:

```
function keyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) isLeft = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) isRight = true;
}

function keyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) isLeft = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) isRight = false;
}
```

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used non-standard codes, so left is usually `LeftArrow` and right is `RightArrow`, but on IE it's just `Left` and `Right` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 1):

You could use e.key, it returns value of the pressed key. So if you press left arrow key `e.key` would be `"ArrowLeft"` and if you press right arrow key `e.key` would be `"ArrowRight"`.

Comment: Note some old browsers used non-standard codes, so those would be just `'Left'` and `'Right'` on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup these codes [Keycode table](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#article-header-id-1)

or

check them interactively here: http://keycode.info/ or http://keycodes.atjayjo.com/

The function `String.fromCharCode` will then convert a unicode number into a character.

For cross browser compatibility you might want to check both the `e.which` and `e.keyCode` properties like below.

```
function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var keyCode= e.which || e.keyCode;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
  alert("The keycode is: "+ keyCode + " and charCode is: " + charStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the character for those key codes, you could just compare them directly:

```
function keyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) isLeft = true;
  if (e.keyCode === 39) isRight = true;
}

function keyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) isLeft = false;
  if (e.keyCode === 39) isRight = false;
}
```

Anyway, keep in mind `e.keyCode` is deprecated, so `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand. Also, you could use an `object` with `boolean` properties instead of individual booleans to make this scale better to more keys:

```js
const pressedKeys = {};

document.onkeydown = ({ key }) => {
  pressedKeys[key] = true;
  
  console.log(Object.keys(pressedKeys).join(' + '));
};

document.onkeyup = ({ key }) => {
  delete pressedKeys[key];
  
  console.log(Object.keys(pressedKeys).join(' + '));
};
```

Just keep in mind some old browsers used non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow '` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead.

Also, if you need to check KeyboardEvent's properties values such as `e.key`, `e.code`, `e.which` or `e.keyCode` you can use https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon!

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

**Disclaimer: I'm the author.**